# Why ExtJS4 Store class doesn't have a property/function to fetch store model?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I really don't understand why model is bound to `proxy` and not to `store`, so if I need a model for the store I have to do something like this:

```
var m = store.getProxy().getModel();
```

Is there any reason for Ext.data.AbstractStore to has no getModel() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong; The Store will not use the model of the proxy but it will use the proxy of the model if you don't define a own proxy for the store. And then you can access the `model` property of the store.

If that didn't made it clear for you give me a comment and I will describe it more in deep along with a example.

**Update**

By now I took a closer look and I cannot really tell you why the getter is missing but the there is a public property `model` on both store and proxy which should contain at least the modelname at the time a instance is created. By now you only get the modelname from the store so you need to resolve the modelconstructor first by calling something like this

```
Ext.ModelMgr.getModel(store.model);
```

**Some additional info**
A more closer look at the source is quite confusing, I have to test it, but it seems there are some inconsistent.

**In short**

***->** the proxy requires a model **->** the store can take the proxy of a assigned model **->** the store (seems to) always set the model of the proxy **->** the proxy (when setting the model) can set the model of the store*

I think they are preparing some things for the upcoming 4.2 release so that people didn't get to confused when their store model is undefined even if they have one assigned to the proxy (for example)

Comment: I think I got it. But why then there is no public `model` property/method? How can I correctly add record to the store with the implicitly created model (from `fields`)?

Comment: I can use methods add/insert because the actually accept object literals with corresponding fields but I don't like this kind of hacks.

Comment: Ops, I'm sorry, looks like I've misunderstood docs. I can use model configuration objects for add/insert methods.

Comment: @SergeyStolyarov You confuse me :) did you get it or do you need clarification? There where to much topics in your comment to answer that in a comment. Please let me know if and for what topic I should alter my answer.

Comment: I'm confused too. If store uses model why it's not available as public method/property? Can you clarify that moment? I think I got proxy/model/store relationship but still don't understand why I can't access model from the store.

Comment: @SergeyStolyarov Please see my edit for additional info on that topic

Comment: technically you can have multiple model types in the same store.